# Data Grouping hiding data from Chart?

Tags: excel, office-2013

I have a chart that works and presents the data as I expect.

When I use Data Grouping of the data and collapse that data region it seems it's no longer available for the chart. Is this correct / is there a way around this (other than creating a summary data set manually?)

This is true when the chart is on the same tab or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting on charts is to not include data from hidden columns and rows in the chart. To change this do the following:

1. Right-click the chart and click **Select Data...**
2. Click the button **Hidden and Empty Cells**
3. Check the box **Show data in hidden rows and columns**